# Reading ES from spark with elasticsearch-spark connector: all the fields are returned

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I've done some experiments in the spark-shell with the elasticsearch-spark connector. Invoking spark:

```
] $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master local[2] --jars ~/spark/jars/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2.jar
```

In the scala shell:

```
scala> import org.elasticsearch.spark._
scala> val es_rdd = sc.esRDD("myindex/mytype",query="myquery")
```

It works well, the result contains the good records as specified in myquery. The only thing is that I get all the fields, even if I specify a subset of these fields in the query. Example:

```
myquery = """{"query":..., "fields":["a","b"], "size":10}"""
```

returns all the fields, not only a and b (BTW, I noticed that size parameter is not taken in account neither : result contains more than 10 records). Maybe it's important to add that fields are nested, a and b are actually doc.a and doc.b.

Is it a bug in the connector or do I have the wrong syntax?

Comment: which version of spark and es connector are you using ?

Comment: Spark 2.0.1 and elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2

Comment: Ok give me a minute to write the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spark elasticsearch connector uses `fields` thus you cannot apply projection.

If you wish to use fine-grained control over the mapping, you should be using `DataFrame` instead which are basically RDDs plus schema.

`pushdown` predicate should also be enabled to translate (push-down) Spark SQL into Elasticsearch Query DSL.

Now a semi-full example :

```
myQuery = """{"query":..., """
val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                     .option("query", myQuery)
                     .option("pushdown", "true")
                     .load("myindex/mytype")
                     .limit(10) // instead of size
                     .select("a","b") // instead of fields
```

Comment: I removed the parentheses after read and it perfectly works. Thanks again @eliasah! It helps for sure!

Comment: Just a last question about this: how to specify the nodes with this syntax? I've read the docs here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext) but I don't find the answer.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong doc. You should refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

Comment: It's `es.nodes` and the node address should contain the port if it's not specified separately

Comment: I can do it in scala: passing --conf spark.es.nodes parameter in spark-shell command seems to make the parameter available to spark.read command. But how can I do the same in pyspark (I don't know how to pass parameters to pyspark command)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134852/discussion-between-eliasah-and-patrick).

Comment: Do you know how I could extract the _id field from ES? It is not recognized if I try to specify it as one of my fields in select clause.

Answer (score 2):

what about calling:

```
scala> val es_rdd = sc.esRDD("myindex/mytype",query="myquery", Map[String, String] ("es.read.field.include"->"a,b"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You want restrict fields returned from elasticsearch _search HTTP API?** (I guess to improve download speed).

First of all, use a HTTP proxy to see what the elastic4hadoop plugin is doing (I use on MacOS Apache Zeppelin with Charles proxy). This will help you to understand how pushdown works.

There are several solutions to achieve this:

**1. dataframe and pushdown**

You specify fields, and the plugin will "forward" to ES (here the _source parameter):

`POST ../events/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=5m&size=50&_source=client&preference=_shards%3A3%3B_local`

> (-) Not fully working for nested fields.
>
> (+) Simple, straightaway, easy to read

**2. RDD & query fields**

With `JavaEsSpark.esRDD`, you can specify fields inside the JSON query, like you did. This only work with RDD (with DataFrame, the fields is not sent).

> (-) no dataframe -> no Spark way
>
> (+) more flexible, more control