# Use Elasticsearch significant-tems aggregation with SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, significant-terms

I am writing/reading datas between Spark dataframes and Elasticsearch using the following code :

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
.option("es.nodes" , [MY_ES_IP])
.option("es.port",[MY_ES_PORT])

   ...

.option("es.index.auto.create","true")
.option("es.resouce.auto.create",[INDEX]/[DATA])
.save([INDEX]/[DATA])
```

and

```
val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
     .option("es.nodes" , [MY_ES_IP])
     .option("es.port",[MY_ES_PORT])

     ...

     .load([INDEX]/[DATA])
```

I want to retrieve the result of a significant-terms request on my datas, but I can't find any example on how to achieve this using Spark.

The DSL request I would like to do :

```
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {[BUCKET REQUEST]}
    },
    "aggregations" : {
        "significant_elements" : {
            "significant_terms" : { "field" : [FIELD NAME] }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that using only the org.elasticsearch.spark.sql lib?

EDIT :

I tried solving the problem with :

```
val myquery = "{\"query\" : {\"terms\" : [BUCKET REQUEST]},\"aggregations\" : {\"significant_elements\" : {\"significant_terms\" : { \"field\" : [FIELD NAME]}}}}"

val df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
                     .option("es.nodes" , [MY_ES_IP])
                     .option("es.port",[MY_ES_PORT])

                     ...

                     .option("query", myquery)
                     .option("pushdown", "true")
                     .load([INDEX]/[DATA])
```

But the dataframe I get in result is the result of the bucket request only.
I'm still looking for how to get the 'significant score' for each [FIELD NAME]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040398/reading-es-from-spark-with-elasticsearch-spark-connector-all-the-fields-are-ret ?

Comment: When I try this, I get a result equivalent to a simple search with my bucket constraint as a result, but no informations from the significant_terms aggregation